# Missing "Use strict" statement

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding. I am receiving this error: "Missing "Use strict" statement" in my Javascript  code.
Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.nav-toggle').on('click',function(){

        $('.main-nav').toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

I do not know where to put `'use-strict';`.
Where do I put the statement?

Comment: This is optional, it shouldn't cause an error.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it?rq=1

Comment: You don't need the leading $.

Comment: @Mathemats Yes he does, that's how you run the code in the jQuery document.ready handler.

Comment: That's not a JavaScript error, but linter error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Barmar said, the use strict is optional, but if you had to place it somewhere the best place I would say you should put it is

```
$(function(){
    "use strict";
    $('.nav-toggle').on('click',function(){

        $('.main-nav').toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

This is where you have to put it whether you use Jquery or Javascript

Comment: Oops I forgot to put a semi colon make sure your `"use strict";` is like this instead of what I wrote

Comment: Sorry for spelling your name wrong @Barmar I am not wearing my glasses right now its a bit blurry for me

Comment: You can just edit your own answer to fix anything you want to fix.  I added the semi-colon for you.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I make too many spelling and syntax mistakes without my glasses I didnt even see the edit button

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function($){
    "use strict";
    $('.nav-toggle').on('click',function(){

        $('.main-nav').toggleClass('open');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.open{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="nav-toggle">Open</button>
  <div class="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Assuming you want to achieve a responsive navbar effect I have added the relevant code to make this easier.

In the jQuery part, I'm creating an anonymous function and passing it the `$` sign so you can use it safely without polluting the global scope. `"use strict"` use is not mandatory but if you want to use place it inside the anonymous function as I did.

Comment: How does this solve the problem that the original question asked about?

Comment: Yes I am making a responsive nav menu :)