# How to make a drop down menu from an icon in a navbar?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, navigation

I have created my dropdown menu to open on hover of the icon, but I want it to actually open on click instead of hover and close when clicked outside the menu. The icon is a simple burger menu icon on the left hand side of the navbar which opens a dropbar that is attached to the left hand side of the page. How would I achieve what I want to with minimal change to my code?

```css
.search {
 display: block;
 margin-left: 1300px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 margin-top: -30px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.burger-menu {
 display: block;
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 margin-top: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000000;
    min-width: 250px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    padding: 30px 16px;
 text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
 <nav>
 <div class="dropdown">
  <input type="image" width="30" height="30" src="images/burger-menu.png" class="burger-menu" />
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">HEADWEAR</a>
    <a href="#">HOODIES/JACKETS/LONG SLEEVES</a>
    <a href="#">SHIRTS</a>
    <a href="#">BOTTOMS</a>
    <a href="#">TOTE BAGS</a>
  </div>
</div>
 <img class="search" src="images/search-icon.png" width="30" height="30">
 </nav>
```

Comment: Don't you have some JS too?

Comment: no JS yet as that is my question, how do I make it open on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use

```
$('.burger-menu').click(function(){
  $('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('show');
});
$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.burger-menu').length) {
        if($('.dropdown-content').is(":visible")) {
            $('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('show');
        }
    }        
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.burger-menu').click(function(){
  $('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('show');
});
$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.burger-menu').length) {
        if($('.dropdown-content').is(":visible")) {
            $('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('show');
        }
    }        
});
});
```

```css
.search {
 display: block;
 margin-left: 1300px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 margin-top: -30px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.burger-menu {
 display: block;
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 margin-top: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000000;
    min-width: 250px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    padding: 30px 16px;
 text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 color: black;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-content.show {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
 <div class="dropdown">
  <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x burger-menu" ></i>  
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">HEADWEAR</a>
    <a href="#">HOODIES/JACKETS/LONG SLEEVES</a>
    <a href="#">SHIRTS</a>
    <a href="#">BOTTOMS</a>
    <a href="#">TOTE BAGS</a>
  </div>
</div>
 <img class="search" src="images/search-icon.png" width="30" height="30">
 </nav>
```

Comment: hi there, this is what i'm after, although it doesn't seem to be working.. It says that there is an error in the Javascript on line 3 column 3 (missing "use strict" statement) and line 6 column 5 (missing "use strict" statement).

Comment: There is not javascript error,it doesn't causes error refer it,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801316/missing-use-strict-statement

Comment: I fixed this javascript problem, however it still doesnt seem to be working?

Comment: either way, the button doesnt seem to be functioning, any idea what the problem is? thanks (btw im very new to coding)

Comment: In Snippet, its working properly button click perform function propely and outside click also working.one thing you need to remember add jquery before custom click function so may be your issue will be solve

Comment: And other way use <span class="burger-menu">menuit<span> instead of input and check

Comment: will that allow me to use an image as the button?

Comment: Take &lt;img src=&quot;pathname&quot;/&gt; inside div insted of span

Comment: please check my answer It is the code I currently have that isn't working

Comment: Hello @mack sorry i am unable to check your answer because in india it is diwali and i am traveling so i am answering from mobile.....so it is take time to check your issue in real device in dreamweaver,sorry for that

Comment: @Mack i have changed some code and update jquery and check in dreamveawer perfectly working,check also in https://jsfiddle.net/831kpf7n/1/ and now update in your code also ,it will work

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of to do this with just CSS is using a checkbox to transition up/down the menu.  I see you're using an input tag, so maybe there's another pure CSS way to do this.

Using jQuery, you can get the desired effect using slideToggle()

```js
$(".icon").on("click", function(){
  $('.dropdown-content').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.search {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 1300px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-top: -30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-top: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000000;
    min-width: 250px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    padding: 30px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL= main.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <h3 class="icon">MY ICON</h3>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">HEADWEAR</a>
                <a href="#">HOODIES/JACKETS/LONG SLEEVES</a>
                <a href="#">SHIRTS</a>
                <a href="#">BOTTOMS</a>
                <a href="#">TOTE BAGS</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img class="search" src="images/search-icon.png" width="30" height="30">
    </nav>
```

Comment: this is for text, I need users to click on an icon to activate the menu not text

Comment: Change the text to an icon/img