# How to use the font-awesome library

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I might be asking a dumb question, but I am a newbie in javascript and its libs.

I came across the same problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46803710/how-to-make-a-drop-down-menu-from-an-icon-in-a-navbar), and in the accepted answer, there was this line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

However, after adding this line I have a navbar icon even though I did not include a img in my html. I also cannot manipulate the position of this icon built with this stylesheet. Can anyone explain what it does in this context? (referring to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46803710/how-to-make-a-drop-down-menu-from-an-icon-in-a-navbar)) I noticed that without this line of code the CSS and Javascript cannot be applied to a simple 
`<img class="search" src="icon.png" width="30" height="30">`

And how is it possible for me adjust the location of the icon with this line of code?

Comment: `Ajax` have nothing to do with the context of your question please change your Title to: **How to use the font-awesome library**

Comment: what do you mean by navbar icon? Link to code would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

font awesome is a css sheet, that when you use "font awesome classes" on a particular element, makes an icon appear. there's no jpgs or anything to mess with.

```
<i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

in a plain html, this will do nothing. but if you add the stylesheet to the page, you will see an address book icon.

all icons are located here: http://fontawesome.io/icons/